# error loading bundle symfony 4

Tags: php, bundle, classnotfoundexception, symfony4

I created a bundle in symfony4 following the symfony 4 [bundle docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html)

my bundle class is this:

```
<?php
namespace Infrastructure\Delivery\Frontend\TodoBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class TodoBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

and I enabled the bundle in config/bundles.php like this:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Infrastructure\Delivery\Frontend\TodoBundle\TodoBundle::class =>['all' => true]
];
```

when I try to run, the symfony server shows me this error:

```
(1/1) ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "TodoBundle" from namespace "Infrastructure\Delivery\Frontend\TodoBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I checked over the files many times but i not found where the error is.
Anybody can help me?

thanks

Comment: Checks your `composer.json` file `autoload` section.

Comment: `"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },`

Comment: it seems is ok no?

Comment: hey try changing 
Infrastructure\Delivery\Frontend\TodoBundle\TodoBundle::class =>['all' => true]
to 
Infrastructure\Delivery\Frontend\TodoBundle::class =>['all' => true]

As you want to load all the classes from the TodoBundle namespace.